# Analyzing BST is balanced Code

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree

I was looking at this python code to check if a Binary Search Tree is balanced. However, I was wondering if someone could explain how

`height = max(left_height, right_height) + 1` comes into play. How does this line of code work to calculate the height. And finally, how this

```
is_left_balanced, left_height = TreeNode.is_balanced(cur_node.left)
is_right_balanced, right_height = TreeNode.is_balanced(cur_node.right)
```

stack recursion is working because once is_balanced(cur_node.left) is called,  its called again when the second TreeNode.is_balanced(cur_node.right) is called.

Im having trouble following the stack trace for this.

Here is the entire code:

```
def is_balanced(cur_node) :
            if (not cur_node) :
                height = 0
                return True, height

            is_left_balanced, left_height = TreeNode.is_balanced(cur_node.left)
            is_right_balanced, right_height = TreeNode.is_balanced(cur_node.right)

            #To get the height of the current node, we find the maximum of the  
            #left subtree height and the right subtree height and add 1 to it
            height = max(left_height, right_height) + 1

            if (not is_left_balanced or not is_right_balanced):
                return False, height

            #If the difference between height of left subtree and height of
            #right subtree is more than 1, then the tree is unbalanced
            if (abs(left_height - right_height) > 1):
                return False, height

            return True, height
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with recursion problems, you should always pay attention to what your base cases are. In this program, there is only one base case: an empty tree, which has a trivially obtainable height of 1 and is, by definition, balanced.
Now assuming a tree is unbalanced if its tallest half has a height of more than 1 plus the height of its other half (that is, its tallest half is taller by at least two levels), or if one of its subtrees is unbalanced, then we get a recursive way of calculating this.

First, return 0 and True for the trivially balanced (empty) tree. We got our base case.

Second, if either of the halves in unbalanced then the tree is unbalanced. This is checked for each subtree, and thus recursion will keep going until finding an empty tree, where it will start returning (picture the case of a tree with only one level, one node. Imagine how the code will run and you'll probably be able to extrapolate from there).

At last, if each subtree is balanced (that's the third case, since we already got that far into the program) then the only way the tree is unbalanced is if one of its subtrees is taller than the other by more than one level. We just check that, and return the opposite of that value.

I hope this helped you understand, feel free to ask me any other questions otherwise!

Comment: I was just asking how the highlighted code works the way it was written.